# REST Web service - JSON request mapping to a java Complex object

Tags: java, json, rest, object, mapping

**I m trying to Map and Send a JSON to a Java Object for Rest Web Service . I m using a RESTful WS with Jersey Java.**

***I am new to this REST, If am not sending correctly please correct me.***

** Here Is a example of My JSON:

MY Json Input in Google Rest Plugin as Raw data is :** [image: I am Calling and Testing MY Rest Service using Google Advance Rest Client.]
as below

JSON Input : 
I need to Map it to :  com.cordys.entity.bean.ClaimTask claimTaskObj

{"taskId":["002481F0-8E9F-11E3-FB97-B80661C15631","002481F0-8E9F-11E3-FB97-B80661C15635"]}

=================================================================================
**I got Below error :**

So every time i send this request the following error appears:

**com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "taskId" (Class com.business.entity.bean.ClaimTask), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@409b5f9c; line: 1, column: 12] (through reference chain: com.business.entity.bean.ClaimTask["taskId"])**
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.unknownFieldException(StdDeserializationContext.java:267)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer.reportUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:673)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:659)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializer.java:1365)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer._handleUnknown(BeanDeserializer.java:725)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:703)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2704)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1315)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:419)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy.readFrom(JacksonProviderProxy.java:139)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:488)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.EntityParamDispatchProvider$EntityInjecta

=================================================================================
**My Rest Web service Method is :**

My Rest Service Method.

```
@POST
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = STATUS_200),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = STATUS_500)
})
@Path("/claimTaskObj")
@Consumes({ "application/json", "application/xml"})
@Produces({ "application/json", "application/javascript", "application/xml" })
public Response claimTaskObj(
        com.business.entity.bean.ClaimTask claimTaskObj,
        @HeaderParam("SAMLart") String samlArt,
        @HeaderParam("otdsticket") String oTAuthenticationHeader,
        @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
    System.out.println("TaskService.claimTask()====== IN");
    // Integration with JAXWS
    //System.out.println("oTAuthenticationHeader ="+oTAuthenticationHeader);
    ClaimTaskJaxWsClient claimTaskClient = new ClaimTaskJaxWsClient();
    ClaimTaskResponse jaxWSResponse = null;
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> inputParameters = uriInfo.getQueryParameters();
    inputParameters.add("task_id", claimTaskObj.getTaskId().get(0));

    String callback = inputParameters.getFirst("callback");
    try {
        jaxWSResponse = claimTaskClient.executeSoapRequest(inputParameters, samlArt,oTAuthenticationHeader);
        return Util.getRespone(jaxWSResponse, callback, 200);
    } catch (com.business.jaxws.task.claimtask.businessFaultDetail e) {
        return Util.getRespone(e.getFaultInfo(), callback, 500);
    }
```

## }

MY Jaxbi Class is :

package com.business.entity.bean;

```
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "taskIdObj", propOrder = {
    "taskId"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "ClaimTask", namespace = "http://schemas.business.com/notification/workflow/1.0")
public class ClaimTask implements Serializable {

    @XmlElement(name = "TaskId", namespace = "http://schemas.business.com/notification/workflow/1.0", required = true)
    protected List<String> taskId;


    public List<String> getTaskId() {
        if (taskId == null) {
            taskId = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        return this.taskId;
    }

    public void setTaskId(String task_Id) {
         if (this.taskId == null) {
             this.taskId = new ArrayList<String>();
         }
         this.taskId.add(task_Id);
    }
    public void setTaskId(List<String> task_Id) {
     if (this.taskId == null) {
        this.taskId = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
    this.taskId.addAll(task_Id);
   }

  }
```

Comment: Try add this to your class you are trying to de-serialize, @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)

Comment: It is a required field, I need to have that field to do any further operation.
So It wont help me if I put @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)  annotation :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can solve and test your web services by implementing following code

```
  ClaimTask claim = new com.howtodoinjava.model.ClaimTask();
  claim.setTaskId("002481F0-8E9F-11E3-FB97-B80661C15631");
  claim.setTaskId("002481F0-8E9F-11E3-FB97-B80661C15635");

  StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
  JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ClaimTask.class);
  Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
  jaxbMarshaller.marshal(claim, writer);

 DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

 // Define a postRequest request
 HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(
"http://localhost:8090/BPMService/v1/tasks/claimTaskObj");

 // Set the API media type in http content-type header
 postRequest.addHeader("SAMLart","XXXXXX");
 postRequest.addHeader("otdsticket","YYYYYYYYYYYYY");
 postRequest.addHeader("content-type", "application/xml");

// Set the request post body
StringEntity userEntity = new StringEntity(writer.getBuffer().toString());
postRequest.setEntity(userEntity);

// Send the request; It will immediately return the response in
// HttpResponse object if any
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);

// verify the valid error code first
int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```